# How can I apply mask to a 16bit image?

Tags: python, opencv

[apply mask like this to an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odRrG.jpg)

How can I apply mask to a 16bit image? It works fine with a 8bit image with this code:

```
image = misc.imread('test.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.Color(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
x = 610
y = 220
w = h = 150
mask = np.zeros(gray.shape[:2], np.uint8)
mask[y:y+h,x:x+w] = 255
res = cv2.bitwise_and(gray, gray, mask = mask)
cv2.imshow("res", res)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

But when I try to do it with a 16 bit.png picture it doesn't work. I tried this code:

```
mask = np.zeros(gray.shape[:2], np.uint16)
mask[y:y+h, x:x+w] = 6535
res = cv2.bitwise_and(gray, gray, mask = mask)
```

I get the error:

> res = cv2.bitwise_and(gray, gray, mask = mask) cv2.error: /home/... : error: (-215) (mtype == CV_8U || mtype == CV_8S) && _mask.sameSize(*psrc1) in function binary_op

Does anybody know how I can apply a mask to my 16 bit image?

Comment: Format your question properly and I'm hoping the missing `=` is just a sloppy too

Comment: Also, why are you using bitwise_and to apply a mask?

Comment: I use bitwise_and to apply a mask, because I don't know how to do it otherwise.. Is there a way to mask a 16bit image?

Comment: As mentioned in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48861282/1170207), `mask` needs to be 8-bit. Why do you want it to be 16 -bit? It's essentially just a boolean array, and since C doesn't have a boolean type, it is a "unsigned int 8" type `uint8_t`.

Comment: I would like to measure light Intensities with a Camera in a grayscale image. I need a lot of information. So 16 bit is the best way for my Question. It's a research project.

Comment: Your mask is an array of `0`s and `255`s. There is just one bit of information. You seem to misunderstand what the `bitwise_and` function is doing. The mask is just a boolean filter on your image, it will not reduce the fidelity of the `gray` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
mask = np.zeros(gray.shape[:2], np.uint16)
mask[y:y+h, x:x+w] = 1
res = gray * mask
```

Comment: I tried it. Did you mean ´mask = np.zeros(gray.shape[:2], np.uint16)?´ But I get an black picture..

Comment: The reason why it's black is because it isn't read as a 16 bit array. I use ´gray = misc.imread('test.png')´ but my image is a 8 bit image. So maybe this is the Problem why your example doesn't work. So how can I read in a 16bit .png image?

Comment: @Anja I fixed the typo. The error that you provided means that your gray image is not gray, it is 3-channel. Multiplication per-element operatior needs equal shape for operands. So, more general answer is - make the shape of mask and image equal and use * orerator.

Comment: @Anja OpenCV has cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH flag to load images with arbitrary depth.

Comment: Use `res = gray * mask[..., np.newaxis]` to expand the mask to all three channels.

Comment: Is it `gray = cv2.imread('test.png', cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)`? Because it's still a 8bit picture?

Comment: Is the question how to apply a mask, or how to read 16-bit images? Because this is a different question and off-topic, and warrants opening a new question on SO.

Comment: Try cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED. And I'm agree with @Cristopth Terasa that it is an offtopic.

Comment: @AlekseyPetrov If you expand your answer with `res = gray * mask[..., np.newaxis]` to make it correct I will give a +1. :-) Though I'd say instead of `np.uint16`, the appropriate type for the mask would be `bool`.

Comment: @CristophTerasa 1)It was assumed and it is seen from the question that gray image is one channel image 2) In that case bool is not appropriate type for the mask, as it should have same type as image to be able to use per-element * operator

Comment: I gave you +1 anyway, but the reasoning is wrong. There is no need for the mask to have a datatype with more than 1-bit, unless you want to use it apply a gain to the image. `numpy` will handle type promotion for multiplication of arrays of different types similar to how C++ handles it, and will promote the boolean array to `np.uint16` for this multiplication. You can check the result_type of an operation using [`np.result_type`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.result_type.html).

Comment: Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 2):

According to the [OpenCV documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=bitwise_and#cv2.bitwise_and), `mask` needs to be 8-bit:

> **mask** – optional operation mask, 8-bit single channel array, that specifies elements of the output array to be changed.

The error message seems to reflect that,

> res = cv2.bitwise_and(gray, gray, mask = mask) cv2.error: /home/... : error: (-215) (mtype == CV_8U || mtype == CV_8S) && _mask.sameSize(*psrc1) in function binary_op

since it tells you that the date type of your mask needs to be either 8-bit unsigned or 8-bit signed (integer).

So the definition of your mask needs to be

```
mask = np.zeros(gray.shape[:2], np.uint8)
mask[y:y+h,x:x+w] = 255
```

like before.